# Intuitive understanding of a logical equivalence

Tags: predicate-logic

I am working through an introductory book on mathematical proofs and I have a question about an equivalence I have proven.

The exercise says to show that
$$\exists x(P(x) \to Q(x))$$
is equal to
$$\forall xP(x) \to \exists xQ(x)$$

I can do that with these steps:
$$\exists x(P(x) \to Q(x))$$
$$\exists x(\lnot P(x) \lor Q(x))$$
$$\exists x \lnot P(x) \lor \exists x Q(x)$$
$$\lnot \forall x P(x) \lor \exists x Q(x)$$
$$\forall xP(x) \to \exists xQ(x)$$

But will someone please help me verbalize why these are equivalent?  They don't seem to be, though I just showed that they are.

I thought an example might help me, so I gave $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ these meanings:

$P(x) \Rightarrow x$ has a first name of "Sam" 
$Q(x) \Rightarrow x$ has a last name of "Bishop"

I would then interpret the first statement like this:

> There is a person such that if he or she has a first name of "Sam" then that person has a last name of "Bishop".

However, I would interpret the second statement like this:

> If everyone has a first name of "Sam", then there is a person who has a last name of "Bishop".

The first statement is only predicated on something being true about one person, but the second statement requires that something be true for everyone.  (As I understand it.)  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first statement says that there is at least one person such that *if* their first name is Sam, then their last name is Bishop. This can be true in two ways: There is a Sam Bishop, or there is somebody who is not named Sam.

- If there is a Sam Bishop, then certainly, if everyone is named Sam, someone is also a Bishop.
- If there is someone who is not named Sam, then "Everyone is named Sam" is false, so "Everyone is named Sam implies someone is a Bishop" is trivially true.

Conversely if "Everyone is named Sam implies someone is a Bishop" is true, then either

- Everyone is named Sam, and so someone is a Bishop, and is therefore Sam Bishop.
- Or there is someone who is not named Sam, and for that person "If his name is Sam, he is a Bishop" is trivially true.

In either case, there is someone such that if his name is Sam, he is a Bishop.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition may be confused by the apparent similarity to the familiar statement $\forall x\;(P(x)\to Q(x))$ vis "all peas are in a queue."

But your existential expression is *not* the same sort of thing at all.

---

Firstly, evaluate the truth of the statement: "If a horse is a car, then it can fly."

> Well, here the antecedent is false, thus the implication is **true**.

---

$\exists x (P(x)\to Q(x))$

"There is something which, if it were a pea, then it would be in a queue."

This statement is satisfied if (1) there is at least one pea that is in a queue, or (2) there is something that is not a pea.   The statement is only falsified if there are no peas that are in a queue *and* there is nothing else but peas.

---

$\forall x\,P(x) \;\to\; \exists Q(x)$

"If all things are peas, then something is in a queue."

Ditto.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have been very helpful, but to make sure I understand this I am going to attempt to answer it myself.

I don't think I gained anything by introducing definitions for $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$.  It's sufficient to focus on the fact that the two statements are true and false in the same situations:

- **If the set of possible values for $x$ is empty, then both statements are false.**  In this case, $x$ doesn't exist, so the first statement is false.  The second statement is also false because the universal quantifier is true over the empty set, making the antecedent true, but again $x$ doesn't exist so the consequent is false.
- **If $P(x)$ is true and $Q(x)$ is false for all possible values of $x$, then both statements are false.**  This is pretty easy to see.
- **If $P(x)$ is true and $Q(x)$ is true for all possible values of $x$, then both statements are true.**  This is also easy to understand.
- **If $P(x)$ is false for any value of $x$, then both statements are trivially true.**  In both cases it's because an implication is true if the antecedent is false.
- **If $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are true for at least one value of $x$, then both statements are true.**  Here the second statement is trivially true again, but the first statement is true according to its straightforward reading.